# Bounding Frobenius norm of pseudo-inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

$\DeclareMathOperator{\F}{\mathrm{F}}$Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}^\prime$ be two $m\times n$ matrix such that $\|\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{A}^\prime\|_{\F}\leq \delta$. Is there any bound for the difference of their pseudo-inverse?
\begin{align}
\|\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}})^{-1}-\mathbf{A}'^{\mathrm{T}}(\mathbf{A}'\mathbf{A}'^{\mathrm{T}})^{-1}\|_{\F}\leq ?,
\end{align}
where $\|.\|_{\F}$ and $()^{\mathrm{T}}$ stand for Frobenius norm and transpose operator, respectively.

Comment: Would a first-order bound in $\delta$ be sufficient for you? It is possible to get one by expanding $A' = A + E$ and using the identity $(A+E)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}EA^{-1} + O(||E||^2)$.

Comment: $AA^t$ need not be invertible.

Comment: Assume that $n>m$ and $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{T}}$ is invertible.